# continuity of supremum of a uniformly continuous function on $[0,1]\times[0,x]$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

It is true that if $f(x,y)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, then $g(x):=sup_{y\in[0,1]}f(x,y)$ is (uniformly) continuous on $[0,1]$. And there are already some answers in this website.

Now my question is the following:

Q1. Let $f(x,y)$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]\times[0,x]$. 
Is it true that $g(x):=sup_{y\in[0,x]}f(x,y)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$?

I have no idea how to prove Q1 since the domain of $y$ is not fixed in this case.

Q2. More generally, if $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $[0,1]\times Y_x$, where $Y_x$ is compact for each $x\in[0,1]$ and continuously varies as $x$ varies continuously. 
Is it true that $g(x):=sup_{y\in Y_x}f(x,y)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$?

Intuitively, Q2 should be true as I think. If $Y_x$ varies discontinuously at some point $x=x_0$, a counterexample may be constructed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does $Y_x$ varying continuously with $x$ mean?

Comment: Like the case of Q1. the interval $Y_x:=[0,x]$ is deformed as $x$ varies continuously. Consider the domain $(x,y)\in ([0,1/2]\times[0,1] \cup [1/2,1]\times[0,1/2])$. This domain has a jump at $x=1/2$. Due to my short knowledge, I do not know if there is a rigorous way to express this. Thank you for response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous on $\{(x,y)\in [0,1]\times [0,1]: y\leq x\}$ then $g(x)=\sup \{f(x,y): y \leq x\}$ is continuous and this follows from the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous on the compact set $\{(x,y)\in [0,1]\times [0,1]: y\leq x\}$. (You just have to imitate the proof of the result when the supremum is taken over all $y \in [0,1]$). For your second question to make sense you have to introduce a metric or a topology on the collection of sets $(Y_x)$. otherwise it makes no sense to talk about $Y_x$ depending continuously on $x$.

Comment: Thank you. I will try more. By the way, is my notation $[0,1]\times [0,x]$ for the set $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]: y \leq x\}$ misleading?

Comment: Yes, it is misleading because the set is not a rectangle.

Comment: I still do not understand. Let $D:=\{(x,y) \in [0,1]\times[0,1] : y \leq x\}$. Since $f(x,y)$ is uniformly continuous on $D$, for given $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|<\delta$ for all $(x_1,y_1) \in D$ and $(x_2,y_2) \in D$. In particular, we have 
 $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x_1,y)-f(x_2,y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$ for all $(x_1,y) \in D$ and $(x_2,y) \in D$. Now the point I do not understand is that when we taking a sup in $y$, the interval of the sup in $y$ depends on $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: (Continued) For instance, when $x_1<x_2$, the inequality $\sup_{y\in D, y \leq x_1} f(x_1,y) \leq \epsilon + \sup_{y\in D, y \leq x_2} f(x_2,y)$ is alright since the set $\{y: 0 \leq y\leq x_2\}$ is larger than the set $\{y: 0 \leq y \leq x_1\}$. I do not know how we take a sup in $y$ to the inequality $f(x_1,y) < f(x_2,y) + \epsilon$.

Comment: @Igottafeelling I will suggest an alternate simpler argument. Define $f_1(x,y)=f(x,y)$ if $y \leq x$ and $f(x,x)$ if $y>x$. You can check two things: a) $f_1$ is continous on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ b) $g(x):\sup \{f_1(x,y):0\leq x \leq 1 ,0\leq y \leq 1\}$. From these you get conituity of $g$ . [It is not necessary to introduce $f_1$, but since you are having difficulty with the proof I am  suggesting this method].

Comment: Thank you very much! So nice extension..

Comment: I understood your suggested argument. You pointed out such an extension is not necessary. I am trying to prove without introducing $f_1$, but it is hard to me. It seems like the region of supremum in $y$ should be independent of $x$ to apply the argument based on the proof of the similar result when the supremum is taken over all y∈[0,1].